# How to override this text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Bootstrap-select CDN:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

in this CDN file there are a text "Nothing selected".
I want to alter this text in my file.
Off course, I can download this js file and altering the text. but i want to use the cdn.

is there a javascript code to do that ?

i tried using :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('.propertyforsale-search .bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle .filter-option span.filter-option.pull-left').html('You Should Select an item');

})(jQuery);
```

My html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="tax_mylanguages" title="Nothing selected" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Nothing selected</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle with the code you have tried

Comment: How are you inserting your dropdown? The button has a title attribute that is currently `title="Nothing selected"`. It looks like the javascript code prioritizes using the title, and otherwise it uses "nothing selected" when the title is missing.

Comment: You are seeing the default text. Bootstrap Select has a number of initial configuration options, of which overriding this text is one. You can set the default text when you instantiate your select box by setting `noneSelectedText `. [See the docs](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with a `title` attribute on `<select>` tag to initialize noneSelectedText option .the whole documentation on [github](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/).

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Choose one of the following...">
 <option>Mustard</option>
 <option>Ketchup</option>
 <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

or you can do it with programmatic way below:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
   noneSelectedText:"Choose one of the following..."
});
```

> ### Skilling of use the third party libraries
>
> this skilling often works fine for myself,so I tell it to you.
>
> - first to see the source that whether existing a copyright doc,because it often contains the documentation location,e.g:Bootstrap-select v1.12.1 (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select).
> - if not existing a copyright doc,you could give a try to google with keyword of the library to find out the documentation.
> - quickly to see the third part examples,if it provided.
> - understand the third party library deeply via its api/documentation.

Comment: While answer looks fine second half (quote of some sort) makes no sense - if it is quote - provide source... If it is just some sort of random remark - format it accordingly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sir,I just emphasize to tell him/she how to use the third library,not only solve his/her question,but I can't find how to highlight it,so I use the quote instead.